# python opencv + ffmpeg makes cpu more busy

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, subprocess

I use cv2 to read frames of local video, then use ffmpeg to push the stream to remote rtmp server.

The command is:

```
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y', '-an',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           # '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', sizeStr,
           '-r', '25',
           '-i', '-',
           # '-c:v', 'libx264',
           # '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'ultrafast',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp]
```

I found that compared with pushing the video directly through ffmpeg, the CPU occupation of "cv2 + ffmpeg" is much more higher. which is: ffmpeg : 5% CPU, cv2 + ffmpeg: 18% CPU

One possible cause is that cv2 turns the frame into BGR, and the ffmpeg turns it into RBG back again, because I found when I removed the option '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', the CPU occupation drops into 5%, but the video pulled from server turns out to be strange, like this:

[image]

Is there any method to reduce the cost of converting BGR into RGB??

Comment: Try replacing `'-pix_fmt', 'bgr24'` with `'-pix_fmt', 'rgb24'` and see that CPU load is the same. For avoiding pixel format conversion, the input pixel format should probably be `yuv420p`. I suspect there is a different reason. Please post a reproducible code sample (include the Python code).

Comment: why are you running a subprocess and piping video data in there? sending data through pipes is inefficient, compared to proper API calls.

Comment: don't worry about BGR/RGB conversion. the video is encoded into YUV anyway, so there's no additional cost, just a different conversion.

Comment: What's the utilization if you just run cv2 (and discard its output)? Also how many threads (logical CPUs) do your have? This could be one place using `-re`/`-readrate` option if it is due to starving ffmpeg input pipe and causing excessive poling... just a speculation. As @Rotem says, post a functional

Comment: Try this: command = ['ffmpeg',
    '-y', '-an',
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-vcodec','rawvideo',
    '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
    '-s', sizeStr,
    '-r', '25',
    '-i', '-',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-f', 'flv',
    rtmp]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what do you mean proper API calls, vs pipes? Which libs are you refering to?

Comment: ffmpeg is also a library.